# React native google pay and stripe integration error

Tags: google-play, stripe-payments, react-native

I'm developing an application with react native and I am using this library
https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe in order to use Google Pay with stripe integration.
I already linked the test key from stripe and the merchant Id from play store.
I have a serious issue though. After running the app, when the Google Pay popup form opens, 
i get the Google Pay dialog but with a message 
"Unrecognized app. Please make sure you trust this app 
before proceeding".
However when I enter a test card and press continue I get an additional error that says
Transaction declined: invalid payment method. [OR-CCSEH-05]
I would appreciate any help.

See image below
[image: teg]

Answer (score 1):

When testing Google Pay, you actually use *real* credit cards.  That said, I'd be doubly positive you've got your environment set to use Test Mode in Google Pay.  Outside of Tipsi, you'd usually set that with the `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST` constant.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

i've contacted google regarding this case, as i've been facing similar one and upon it's inspection i've received the following reply:

Thanks for being Patient. I apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Upon checking, I understand that you're unable to add testing cards. I would like to inform you that testing cards can't be added to Google Payment profile as payment Method.

Thanks!

upon further investigation by Stripe it self i've been assured:
For a bit of context on how Google Pay works to test payments. When you’re using your test mode API keys, the actual details of the card are ignored, and they get replaced with the Stripe 4242 test card. To test authentication you will not be able to add the test cards to your Google Pay account however there is a work around for this, you add our 3DS test cards to Chrome and use the PaymentRequest button with them (making sure to choose them, and not Google Pay itself). Unfortunately there is no direct method to testing this in your the app.

so setting WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST at 5th step of their tutorial should be sufficient and then use your real card. 
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial